# How do I extract only the shipping address and not the billing address using SQL and join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, filtering

I am trying to return FirstName, LastName, Line1, City, State, and ZipCode from the Customers table and the Addresses table using a join.  I am to return one row for each customer, but only return addresses that are the shipping address for a customer.  This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Line1, City, State, ZipCode
FROM Customers JOIN Addresses
    ON (Customers.CustomerID = Addresses.CustomerID);
```

These are the fields for the Customers table:

```
CustomerID EmailAddress Password FirstName LastName ShippingAddressID BillingAddressID
```

These are the fields for the Addresses table:

```
AddressID CustomerID Line1 Line2 City State ZipCode Phone Disabled
```

I tried to use a ad hoc relationship and it did not work.  I do not know how to filter out only the shipping address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join has to be based on AddressIds, not CustomerIds, ie:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Line1, City, State, ZipCode
FROM Customers JOIN Addresses
ON (Customers.ShippingAddressId = Addresses.AddressID);
```

Comment: and... how did you know that?

Comment: Because of the title `How do I extract only the shipping address and not the billing address using SQL and join?`

Comment: And the OP: `I am to return one row for each customer, but only return addresses that are the shipping address for a customer.`

Comment: Hmmm Nice, but 1 IMP. thing was missing, join on Customer ID is also required. I have edited you ans. please check.

Comment: Since either one of these fields are a primary or foreign key, would this be considered an ad hoc relationship?  I was told to be careful with ad hoc relationships?  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: @AK47 if constraints are OK (`ShippingAddressId` and `BillingAddressId are unique and there are foreign keys `Customer.ShippingAddressId` => `Address.AddressId` and `Customer.BillingAddressId` => `Address.AddressId`), you don't need to join on `CustomerId`. It is useful if `Customers` table is incoherent (e.g. two customers reference the same shipping address).

Comment: Sorry @user3547834, I don't know ad hoc relationships, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you need to return Customer detail even if doesn't have an address.

If so, use Left Join

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Line1, City, State, ZipCode
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Addresses
    ON (Customers.CustomerID = Addresses.CustomerID and 
Customers.ShippingAddressID=Addresses.AddressID)
```

Comment: All customers have a billing and shipping address, but sometimes the address are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think as you are using inner join which is issue, it will bring record if exists in both table, instead use Left join.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Line1, City, State, ZipCode
FROM Customers Left JOIN Addresses
    ON Customers.CustomerID = Addresses.CustomerID and Customers.ShippingAddressId = Addresses.AddressID;
```